# Python - Reading in data from csv and then writing to new csv with data and file number from loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My objective is to:

- Read in all of the files from the directory which start with letter "Z".
- Read in the Temperature column from each .csv in the directory.
- Open a new .*csv*:

  - Add the Temperature column to the new .*csv*.
  - Add a column, "File #" to this new *.csv*, and iterate 1,2,3,4 based on the number of files that I read in through the loop.
- I'm currently stuck with how to:

  - Create the .csv file and open it in every loop.
  - Add the Temperature Column and the File # column (with File # incremented) into the .csv file.

import pandas as pd
import csv
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

```
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Time','ms','Temperature']
    df=df.astype(str)
    df["Temperature"] = df["Temperature"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # I need to add the column, "File #" to the Dataframe

    df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', columns=[['Temperature','File #']] header=False)
    # Is df.to_csv is the best option here?
    
    # Then, I need to iterate the file # for the next loop.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample of your expected output? Also, you should add some check for the file name, starting from 'Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find my suggestions below - hope this helps!

```
for i, f in enumerate(filenames):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Time','ms','Temperature']
    df=df.astype(str)
    df["Temperature"] = df["Temperature"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # I need to add the column, "File #" to the Dataframe
    df['File #'] = i
    
    df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', columns=[['Temperature','File #']] header=False)
    # Is df.to_csv is the best option here? - probably yes
```